# Why I got error 150 when migrating this code in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
Schema::create('details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('details_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id');
        $table->string('author', 255);
        $table->string('publisher', 255);
        $table->integer('year');
        $table->longText('description');

        $table->foreign('book_id')->references('book_id')->on('books')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('category_id');
        $table->string('category_name', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('book_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('title', 255);

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('category_id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I want to make these 3 tables. But I keep getting errno 150 which is incorrectly formed. I cannot find the solution.

Comment: Please provide full error message.

Comment: Most likely because in your `details` migration the table `books` doesn't exist yet: `->on('books')` can't find the table you want to reference

Answer (score 2):

I think you should give the data type of books table primary key i.e id as unsignedBigInteger() . Because, you want to make foreign key of this table with this column in details table .So, just add a unsignedBigInteger() to id column. hopefully your problem will be fixed.